# Python re.sub to replace 3 or more of same character with 1

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find characters that are repeated 3 times or more, for example I want to take the following strings:

(`'aaa'`, `'buuuuut'`, `'oddddddddd'`)

and replace all occurrences of three or more of a letter with only one:

(`'a'`, `'but'`, `'od'`).

I've tried following code

```
s=re.sub(r'(\w)\3*',r'(\w)',s)
```

but it results in a compile error.

What regex do I need to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> mystr = 'buuuuuttttt'
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1', mystr)
'but'
>>> mystr = 'buttt'
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1', mystr)
'but'
>>>
```

Comment: @fanti I've tried your regex on 'buuuuuttttt' but it results in 't'. What could be the problem?

Comment: This doesn't work where the character is repeated exactly 3 times... :) Try `buttt` for instance

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - Lol.  Wow, those are some cool kids if they are browsing coding sites at their age. ;)

Comment: @iCodez I've seen 10 year olds who started Python at 8. They put me to shame :( I'm just so goddam jealous. :P

Comment: 10 years old? Ahh I am 13

Comment: @Vik2015 - Then I guess you are a cool kid. ;)  Keep up the good work and don't stop learning.  Starting to code at your age means you have exceptionally great potential to do some really cool things in life.

Comment: @iCodez, Thanks :) I hope so too :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = 'abbcccdddd'
>>> s = re.sub(r'(\w)\1(\1+)',r'\1',s)
>>> s
'abbcd'
```

Comment: This one looks even easier than `re.sub(r'(.)\1{3,}', r'\1', mystr)`

Comment: ...and I see I've fixed my code from (\w)(\1+) to (\w)\1(\1+) and ended up with what fanti had posted

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like this:

```
s = re.sub(r'(\w)\1\1+', r'\1', s)
```